# Remote debugging Internjs that runs on selenium chromedriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, remote-debugging, selenium-chromedriver, intern

I try to remotely debug tests run by Internjs. 
Basically it is a Chrome that is run by Selenium and Chromedriver.

I set up Chromedriver debuggerAddress option as

```
debuggerAddress: '127.0.0.1:8765'
```

Now when I run tests Selenium waits some time and than fails with message:

```
FATAL ERROR
UnknownError: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session / {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","name":"tests/intern_local","idle-timeout":60,"selenium-version":"2.44.0","chromeOptions":{"debuggerAddress":"127.0.0.1:8765"}}}] unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:8765
from chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301326 (093c7e07b4a916b690e784b0374c7f618f1ea4be),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.64 seconds
```

I'm not sure what I have to do so that chrome would connect to server.

I did try:

- Running chromedriver on that port `./chromedriver_2.11 --port=8765`
- Running chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=8765`

But I have no other ideas how to start a chrome debug server.

Useful links that I did try that that did not work for me:

- [Remote debugging protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol)
- [Remotely debugging Chrome Desktop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Chrome_Desktop)
- [Chromedriver Capabilities (aka ChromeOptions)](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

**Update 1** Forcing Chromedriver to use a Chrome instance with remote debugging on

Run a new Chrome instance as in [Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Chrome_Desktop)

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d -t 'chrome-remote_data_dir')
```

In intern set

```
intern.capabilities = {
  'selenium-version': '2.44.0'
, 'chromeOptions': {
    debuggerAddress: '127.0.0.1:9222'
  }
};
```

Now when you run Intern tests Intern will use your previously open Chrome instance. Now you can open `localhost:9222` and you'll see that you can debug that tab in which tests run. However for me I'm just able to see that remote tab, but clicking on it does nothing.

I also tried Firefox WebIDE. I tried to connect to `localhost:9222`, it starts to load and after some time it says that it can't connect.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something similar this evening, without using a framework. I opened a webdriver session & added the remote debugger capabilities.
It seems that it is not possible to run a webdriver session & remote debug at the same time. I asked some Google guys to verify that, but haven't received an answer yet.

Comment: So, I was wondering if that is true (webdriver session + remote debug at the same time = not possible).

Comment: From what I debugged some time ago, it seems like both tools use the same debugger protocol, respectively the same server endpoint to connect to the browser.
If that is already in control by one of the processes, the other isn't able to connect.

Not verified by anyone who has more expertise than I do, but that was the behaviour I observed.