# How to set "debuggerAddress" chromeOption via selenium-webdriver javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-testing

There is a list of [recognized "capabilities"](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) in Webdriver and "debuggerAddress" is among them.

But I can't find a way to set such option neither in [Capabilities](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_Capabilities.html#Capabilities.chrome) class  not in [CromeOptions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver_Options.html) in javascript api.

As I can see in several questions "debuggerAddress" option (or capability?) is possible to set in Python api.

What I try is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948101/remote-debugging-internjs-that-runs-on-selenium-chromedriver),
from node app

1. To link app to already started webdriver (cromedriver.exe). This is ok with

   `webdriver.Builder().usingServer( 'http://localhost:9515' )`
2. Ask webdriver not to start new Chrome instance but instead to link to already started with `--remote-debugging-port=XXXXX` Chrome parameter. And this should be done with `"debuggerAddress"` option/capability, but I can't realize how to do it with javascript api.

Answer (score 8):

It appears there is no API exposed for that. But I managed to get it to work using this hack:

```
    var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
    var options = new chrome.Options();
    options.options_["debuggerAddress"] = "127.0.0.1:6813";
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();
```

See [this](https://gist.github.com/SergeyAvd/3466c9e2330b3a89e7d00a19ccd59f57) for the full basic example.

Comment: This is the only solution I have found that works.

Answer (score 1):

After running Chrome with option `--remote-debugging-port=9222`, with chromedriver 105 I got it working with `debuggerAddress()` method of `chrome.Options()`, like this:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.debuggerAddress("127.0.0.1:9222");
var driver = await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(chromeOptions).build();

await driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Hope it helps :)